# Internet Explorer suddenly stopped displaying images with parameters

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

This issue had been working without problems for the last year. Starting yesterday, all of our product photos stopped displaying in all versions of Internet Explorer. All of our product photos use a script to append a watermark PNG to the JPG before it is displayed. Thus, instead of serving a normal photo like this:

```
<img scr="http://www.domain.com/image.jpg">
```

Our code is properly displayed like this:

```
<img scr="http://www.domain.com/watermark.php?size=300&photo=./image.jpg">
```

Chrome, Safari, and Firefox display the images properly. Internet explorer displays the image not found "x". We need our images displaying properly as they did before in Internet Explorer.

I will add that if we remove the parameter script from the url, and display the image as normal, the images display in IE fine.  But we need the script to run on ou

Comment: Did you do any troubleshooting? Check if the page exists? Try encoding the URL, the / might be doing some nasty things.

Comment: `photo=./image.jpg` why would you put the `./` in the parameter rather than the code?

Comment: Also "Internet Explorer" is too vague here.  Which version? On which Windows OS? On PocketPC? On PC, on Tablet? IE3? IE6? IE8? IE9? Very vague on details here.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example, which performs a specific processing, every time it is executed:

```
<?php 

$base_img = 'final.png'; 

$tgt_img1 = 'actual.png'; 
$tgt_img2 = 'watermark.png'; 

/* ----- Watermark Operations You wanna do ----- */

imagepng(..., $base_img, ...);

?>


<!-- Give the source the name of your generated image directly -->
<img src="<?php echo $base_img; ?>" alt="*" /><br><br>
```

Hopefully this sample code will help. This is better that passing direct PHP url in the source of the image

Comment: What does this have to do with a problem caused by failing to urlencode a slash in `&photo=./image.jpg`?

Comment: I got the issue. Since I've not got enough info on why this is happening, whether its the path or the relativity of the path, what version of browser, in what OS. I thought presenting an alternative which would avoid the problem would be better.

Comment: Do you really have to use trigonometry to convert from png to jpg in PHP?  Ugh. I've only done it in Java and C# before and thankfully that wasn't needed.

Comment: Hehe. Good for you Man. This is something related to what I needed to do based on some scenario. This code just plays an example here.

Comment: _“Since I've not got enough info […]”_ … I am just going to answer _something_ anyway? Sorry, but that’s just nonsense.